# I want to get rid this magnifico popup jquery effect

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

Thank you so far for your help. But this one is quite tricky, which is jquery stuff that I don't have much knowledge about.

So yeah, I want my image to be clickable.

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12 mt-3">
          <a class="portfolio-box" href="img/portfolio/fullsize/2.jpg">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="img/gofar_square.jpg" alt="">
            <div class="portfolio-box-caption">
              <div class="project-category text-white-50">
                Category
              </div>
              <div class="project-name">
                Gofar
              </div>
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
```

But everytime I click the image, there's always a pop-up gallery appear stating that it doesn't find the image.

I did inspect element and turned out the culprit is the jquery file (magnifico popup)

What I want to ask is...how can I get rid of this effect? Because I just want to make an image that's clickable to another html page.

Thank you as always.

Answer (score 0):

Your image should be clickable, it depends what you want to happen here.

You have **class="portfolio-box"** that may trigger a different effect.

A simple `<a  href="YourImage.jpg">
            <img src="YourImage.jpg" alt=""></a>` will suffice.

Please tell us more about what you want to happen once you click on it.

Comment: no, everytime i click the image there's always a pop-up message "your image is not found". There's a bit mistake on the code above, it should be a page open when i click the image. I think it's all about jquery popup magnifico effect that i want to get rid of.

Comment: nevermind, i create the new overlay effect and get rid of all initial css. Thank you.